# Angular UI Router Otherwise fails to redirect

Tags: angularjs, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to setup and 404 page on my website by using

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");
```

but this only works for URLs that do not have multiple slashes/parameters. The following is all of my URLs and states in the same order as in my code:

- Home – /
- 404 – /404
- About – /about-us
- Privacy – /privacy-policy
- Terms – /terms-conditions
- Subscribe – /subscribe
- Author – /author/:author
- Topic – /:category/page/:pageNumber
- Post – /:category/:title

If there is a url with two slashes (Ex: /qwkhdjqkwnd/q1weuih), my app thinks it's a Post and tries to fetch information but this obviously fails – it does not know that this is not a valid URL, and thus does not redirect to my 404 page.

What's the best practice for this? Should I allow the app to try and fetch data using the invalid URL and, redirect the state when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for an undefined object and redirecting to /404 worked for my purposes.